# How does this transistor behave as the base voltage is increased?

Tags: transistors, npn, saturation

Consider this transistor. How do the voltages `Vb`, `Vc` and `Ve` vary as we increase `Vin` from `0v` towards `5v`?

[image: schematic]

My current understanding is that:

1. If `Vb < 0.65v` then no current flows.

   **So, if `Vin < 0.65v` then `Vb = Vin`, `Vc = 5v` and `Ve = 0v`.**
2. As `Vb` increases above `0.65v`, then `Ve = Vb - 0.65v` and `Ie = Ve / 1000Ω`. If we consider the base current `Ib ≈ Ie / 100` to be negligible, then `Ic = Ie` and `Vc = 5 - Ic * 2000Ω`.

   For example, `Vb = 1v` => `Ve = 0.35v` => `Ic = Ie = 0.35mA` => `Vc = 4.3v`.

   When `Vb = 2.1v`, then `Ve = 1.45v` => `Ic = Ie = 1.45mA` => `Vc = 2.1v`. Since `Vc` has dropped to equal `Vb`, the transistor enters saturation.

   **So, if `0.65v < Vin < 2.1v` then the transistor is in active mode, `Vb = Vin` and `Ve = Vb - 0.65v`.**

I'm less sure about what happens as we continue to increase `Vin`:

3. Am I right in thinking that as `Vb` increases slightly higher than `2.1v`, the transistor continues to behave as it does in active mode? `Ve` continues to increase and `Vc` continues to decrease until `Vc - Ve = 0.2v`?

   That condition is reached at `Vb = 2.25v` => `Ve = 1.6v` => `Ic = Ie = 1.6mA` => `Vc = 1.8v`.

   **Is it true that for `2.1v < Vin < 2.25v` the transistor is in saturation, but still `Vb = Vin` (because still `Ib ≈ Ie / 100`) and `Ve = Vb - 0.65v`?**
4. Is it correct that for `Vb > 2.25v`, `Vc - Ve = 0.2v`? Is it still true that `Vb - Ve = 0.65v`?

   If so then, for example, `Vb = 3v` => `Ve = 2.35v` and `Vc = 2.55v` => `Ie = 2.35mA` and `Ic = 1.225mA` => `Ib = Ie - Ic = 1.125mA`? So `Vin = Vb + Ib * 1000Ω = 4.125v`?

   **Is it true that for `2.25v < Vin < 5v` the transistor is in saturation, `Vb < Vin` (because `Ib` is no longer negligible) and `Ve = Vb - 0.65v`?**

**Edit:** If I try this in a simulator and change the resistor values from 1kΩ & 2kΩ to 10Ω & 20Ω, it becomes obvious that `Ve = Vb - 0.65v` no longer holds once we reach part 4, `Vc - Ve = 0.2v`. Above 2.5v, as `Vb` increases, `Ve` increases more slowly than `Vb`. How do I calculate `Ve` in this situation, as it's not simply `Vb - 0.65v`?

Comment: why not solder up a transistor and three resistors (and a 1K linear potentiometer to vary Vin) and find out? There are also simulators you could use instead of real hardware, but in this case the hardware is simple ... and inexpensive.

Comment: Why not use a simulation tool.

Comment: @user_1818839 - Thanks for your comment. I have tried this in a simulator and the resulting graphs seem to agree with my numbers, but I want to verify that I correctly understand the theory that led to these numbers. In particular, is it true that in saturation, we still have `Ve = Vb - 0.65v`? And does `Ic = β * Ib` continue to hold during the first part of saturation, until it is "replaced" by `Vc - Ve = 0.2v`?

Comment: @user_1818839 - Please see my edit. I have found out that in part 4, it is *not* true that `Ve = Vb - 0.65v`.

Comment: Do you know that in real life Vbe is not constant? But in hand calculation, we assume for simplicity that the Vbe is constant and value is between 0.6...0.7V Also, how do you define when saturation begins? Vb = Vc or something else?

Comment: And if you want to find the voltage at the emitter when BJT is saturated you can use this equation $$V_E = \left(\frac{V_{IN} - V_{BE}}{R_B} +\frac{V_{CC} -V_{CEsat}}{R_C}\right)\cdot R_E||R_B||R_C  $$

Comment: @G36 - Yes, I understand that assuming `Vbe(on) = 0.65v` is an approximation. Is there a commonly-used approximation for `Vbe(sat)` (I don't think this would be a constant)?

Comment: @G36 - Saturation begins when `Vc = Vb` - this is when we move from part 2 to part 3 above. However, AFAICT the transistor's behaviour doesn't change until `Vc = Ve + 0.2v` - i.e. when we move from part 3 to part 4.

Comment: Transistor's behavior begins to change when the base-collector junction begins to conduct current (forward-biased) when Vb > Vc = 0.5V thus Vbe(sat) = 0.2V + 0.5V = 0.7V.

Answer (score 4):

For \$ 0.65V < V_{IN} < 2.2V \$ your calculations are correct.

What happens after that (\$ V_{IN} > 2.2V \$) is as follows. The transistor is saturated, with \$V_{CE}\$ at a minimum of 0.2V. This can further diminish a little (to perhaps 0.1V) if base current continues to rise. I will assume it remains more or less constant at around 0.2V, and I will neglect any further reduction.

There can be no further increase in collector current since \$V_C\$ is at a minimum, and the voltage across \$R_C\$ is unable to rise. Consequently, we have entered a regime in which the usual gain equation \$I_C=\beta \cdot I_B\$ is no longer true. Also, because of this, we may no longer assume that \$I_C \approx I_E\$. Henceforth, as \$V_{IN}\$ continues to rise, since the transistor is no longer operating in its active region, we must rely on Kirchhoff's and Ohm's laws to determine state.

Kirchhoff's Voltage Law predicts that collector voltage \$V_C\$, in this saturated state, will be:

$$\begin{aligned}
V_C &= V_E + V_{CE}
\newline
\newline
&= V_E + 0.2V
\end{aligned}$$

We know the relationship between base voltage \$V_B\$ and emitter voltage \$V_E\$ must be:

$$ V_B = V_E + 0.65V $$

This 0.65V difference is subject to the diode equation, because base current is about to rise significantly, as we will see, but I will assume that the potential difference between base and emitter is fixed at 0.65V, to simplify the analysis.

We also know, by Ohm's law that base current is:

$$\begin{aligned}
I_B &= \frac{V_{IN} - V_B}{R_B} \newline
\newline
&= \frac{V_{IN} - (V_E + 0.65V)}{R_B} \newline
\newline
&= \frac{V_{IN} - 0.65V - V_E}{R_B}
\end{aligned}$$

We can also use Ohm's law to find \$I_E\$:

$$ I_E = \frac{V_E}{R_E} $$

and \$I_C\$:

$$\begin{aligned}
I_C &= \frac{5V - V_C}{R_C}
\newline
\newline
&= \frac{5V - 0.2V - V_E}{R_C}
\newline
\newline
&= \frac{4.8V - V_E}{R_C}
\end{aligned}$$

Kirchhoff's Current Law relates \$I_C\$, \$I_B\$ and \$I_E\$:

$$ I_E = I_B + I_C $$

Substitute in the three expressions we have for \$I_B\$, \$I_C\$ and \$I_E\$, to get an equation relating \$V_{IN}\$ and \$V_E\$, and then solve for \$V_E\$:

$$ \frac{V_E}{R_E} = \frac{V_{IN} - 0.65V - V_E}{R_B} + \frac{4.8V - V_E}{R_C}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
V_E = \frac{R_E}{R_B R_C + R_C R_E + R_B R_E} (V_{IN} R_C - 0.65 R_C + 4.8 R_B)
\newline
\newline
\text{for} \space 2.2V < V_{IN} < 5V
\end{aligned}$$

Here's the circuit simulated, with a graph comparing our calculated (orange) and simulated (blue) \$V_E\$ vs. \$V_{IN}\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f79htA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Given these two equations from earlier:

$$ V_C = V_E + 0.2V $$
$$ V_B = V_E + 0.65V $$

it's easy to see that collector and base voltages follow the same "curve", only slightly higher.

The only part of your reasoning (your point 3) that I disagree with is the statement that \$V_B\$ continues to be equal to \$V_{IN}\$ when \$V_{IN}\$ rises above 2.2V. This is not true, because base current will rise with \$V_{IN}\$ after the transistor becomes saturated, and is no longer negligible. Here's a graph of base current \$I_B\$ across the entire range of \$V_{IN}\$ from 0v to 5V:

[image]

This current flows through \$R_B\$, causing a voltage drop which makes \$V_B\$ differ from \$V_{IN}\$.